# Netsuite API authenticate validation

Tags: node.js, authentication, netsuite

I have sample mobile app with username and password authentication,need to valid my sample app username & password exists in netsuite based website. Please provide API info and steps to access netsuite based user info to valid my app login, currently we are using nodeJS API in app. I mean if signup/existing customer from my app would exists or not in netsuite based website

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to log in as a customer or employee you need to ensure the records have login access, and credentials set, in NetSuite.

Not completely sure from your post if you are trying to log them in, or just access your NetSuite instance and see if they exist in the NetSuite instance, though.

Can you provide more information, and clearly state what you have tried?  Code samples are a very nice thing to include, along with the errors you are receiving.